# Error when I try to retrieve a returned value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to execute a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure to get returned value, I use this code:

```
 var conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"];

 string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;

 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
 using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
 {
  cmd.CommandText = "DicRegisterUser";
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserDeviceKey", UserDeviceKey);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserFullName", UserFullName);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", UserEmail);
  //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PBKey", "");

      var returnParam = new SqlParameter
  {                 
    ParameterName = "@PBKey",                   
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    Size = 50                            
  };                
  cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParam);

  cn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cn.Close();               

  return  (string)cmd.Parameters["@PBKey"].Value;
}
```

Also the stored procedure:

```
return a nvarchar (50)
```

but I got this error:

> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar
>   value '669BA3A1-4172-467C-989F-1F140E9407B7' to data type int.

Comment: share your store procedure `DicRegisterUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the the parameter @UserDeviceKey is defined to take integer values as input but, you are passing a uniqueidentifier as the parameter

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure in SQL Server **cannot** use a `Varchar(50)` value as it's return type. Stored procedures **always** return an `INT` that indicates whether or not the call was successful, or how many rows were affected (for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` statements).

You can set an `OUTPUT` parameter of type `VARCHAR(50)` to whatever value you want (and you're already doing that, I hope!), but you cannot use that `VARCHAR(50)` in your `RETURN ...`  statement.